Set build-override for dependency
I'm depending on a crate that has build-override.opt-level = 3 set for all build profiles, because its build script takes very long to run with the default opt-level for build scripts, which is 0.
How do I make the build script compile with the same opt-level value in a downstream binary?

Only the end application can decide on opt level. You will have to include it in the docs.

Thanks. This is the end application though. Updated the question to reflect that.

I'm not 100% sure if I got you right, but If your goal is to override the opt-level for this very crate you are depending on, then you can override it in your crate Cargo.toml this way:
# The `foo` package will use the -Copt-level=0 flag.
[profile.dev.package.foo]
opt-level = 0

This will only apply for the dev profile and only take affects to a crate named foo in your dependency tree.
Just in case, if this very crate you are depending on is only one of the build-dependencies you must override it this way:
# Set the settings for build scripts and proc-macros.
[profile.dev.build-override]
opt-level = 0

This still applies for the dev profile, but is not anymore dependency specific.
Read more about it in the docs: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html?highlight=build-override#overrides

The crate I'm depending on has a build script. I want that build script to be compiled with opt-level=3.

Then the 2nd approach [profile.dev.build-override] should work.
